# how can I pass a dictionary from javascript to flask?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I want to pass a dictionary (button_state) from javascript to python using flask and jquery.
On the jquery side, I have:

```
$(".btn#submit").click(function(event){
    newdata = JSON.stringify(buttons_state);
    console.log("submission button POST attempt: " + newdata)

    $.ajax({
        url: '/submission',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: newdata,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

});
```

On the server side:

```
@app.route('/submission', methods=['POST'])
def submission():
    info = request.get_json(silent=False)
    return info
```

But I am getting an Error 500:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in make_response
    reraise(TypeError, new_error, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/flask/app.py", line 1974, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Users/timrand/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a dict.
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2018 07:53:48] "POST /signUpUser HTTP/1.1" 500 -

It seems that the server code is not correctly retrieving the data or that there is a problem with the way that the data was converted to a string by JSON.stringify. I have read many others with the same problem, and have tried the solutions on stack overflow, but only get Error 400.

Comment: If you could show the complete error your flask application is showing then it might be easy to know what actually the problem is ?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the client-side submission to a valid JSON or even pass empty dict (`newdata="{}"`). This could help you determine whether your problem is client- or server side.

Comment: `newdata` is a string here, could this be the issue? What about adding `force=True` in `get_json` arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send a javascript dictionary to python-flask via ajax, using another approach and it works perfectly. In case **the problem is that the server does not find the data** (it is most likely), you can take inspiration from the approach that I describe (which seems the simplest in my opinion)

My configuration is different, you can see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870184/get-data-from-html-and-do-some-operation-on-it-and-pass-the-data-back-to-the-f/52883461#52883461) or [this link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/) for more information.

**1. On the HTML side:**

Respectively Loading jquery and adding a dynamic path to my site:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"> </script>

<script type=text/javascript>$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}; </script>
```

**2. On the Jquery side:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn#submit').bind('click', function(){
        var dict = {};
        dict.key1 = "value1";
        dict.key2 = "value2";

        new_dict = JSON.stringify(dict);

        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_submission', {
            dict: new_dict,
        },function(data){
            alert("Data from flask" + data.new_dict_flask);
        });
    });
});
```

**3. On the Flask side:**

```
@app.route('/_submission')
def submission():
    new_dict_flask = request.args.get('dict')
    return jsonify(new_dict_flask=new_dict_flask)
```